# Adding site from a folder few levels inside wwwroot, throws Error 404

Tags: iis, git

I am completely new to IIS, I am trying all this on Windows Server 2012. What I am trying to do is, I have setup a Bonobo git server in iis which is at wwwroot/Bonobo.Git.Server level.

I have created a repository in this git server which is at wwwroot/Bonobo.Git.Server/App_Data/Repositories/mail, I have committed all my files in this folder.

I created a new website and set the physical path to wwwroot/Bonobo.Git.Server/App_Data/Repositories/mail

But when I run this site it throws HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

You can check the whole error here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzY0U.jpg

I have also tried adding a Virtual Directory, giving all the permissions.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? As I'm running into the same thing as well.